# How to shade all occurrences of highlighted word in custom editor plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, text-editor, highlighting

I have an eclipse custom editor plugin. How do I make all occurrences of highlighted word shaded just like the java editor? I wonder if I have to get styled text control and manually manipluate it to get this done or if there is a framework done to make this job easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a JFace text annotation type and just manage annotations for those locations.  As with most things, you'll find examples of this done in JDT.